# I am running node.js and express and i'm getting this error "Cannot read property 'build' of undefined"

Tags: node.js, express

I am setting up handler of singup in **user.js**

this is **user.js** from controller folder using node.js and express

```
exports.signup = function(req, res, next){
    console.log(req.body.Password1 + " " + req.body.Email1);
    const newUser = models.User.build({
        email: req.body.Email1,
        password: generateHash(req.body.Password1)  
    });
    return newUser.save().then(result => {
        passport.authenticate('local', {
            successRedirect: "/",
            failureRedirect: "/signup",
            failureFlash: true
        })(req, res, next);
    })
}
```

I expect to insert email and password in the database table called **user**
after going successfully  to homepage
but actually, I'm getting this error

> " TypeError: Cannot read property 'build' of undefined"

Comment: What is your `models`?

Comment: `models.User` is undefined, you have to check why `models` doesn't have this property object

Comment: here is my model has **User.js**

Comment: thank, it worked i declared my {modeles.users} wrong